# 500 Internal Server Error - when assigning data from json_decode to variables

Tags: php

I am sending some form data form an `AngularJs` app to my php script. So far I've been unable to get Angular to send a "regular" `POST` request (it sends JSON data instead), so I figured I'd just decode it with `php`, then use the results

I am now having trouble referencing the results. I get `"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error` upon sending data to my script.

Here's my php code:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

$data = json_decode($data);
var_dump($data);

$fromName = $data["fromName"];
$fromEmail = $data["fromEmail"];
$msg = $data["inputMsg"];
```

The `var_dump($data)` returns this:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["fromName"]=>
  string(4) "djea"
  ["fromEmail"]=>
  string(13) "djea@djea.com"
  ["inputMsg"]=>
  string(7) "testMsg"
}
```

can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: A **500* error sounds a little to **serious** to just be because you are addressing an object as if it were and array. I think there is more to this than you are telling us.

Comment: I changed it to `json_decode($data, true)`, got an array, error disappeared. This is a part of a bigger AngularJS app, but I decided to only post the relevant code. Waiting for the time limit so I can accept the anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `true` as a second variable to [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get associative array.

```
$data = json_decode($data, true);

$fromName = $data["fromName"];
$fromEmail = $data["fromEmail"];
$msg = $data["inputMsg"];
```

`json_decode` returns object if you do not pass second variable as a `true`.

```
$data = json_decode($data);

$fromName = $data->fromName;
$fromEmail = $data->fromEmail;
$msg = $data->inputMsg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since it's an object and not an array, you need to access the elements like this:

```
$fromName = $data->fromName;
$fromEmail = $data->fromEmail;
$msg = $data->inputMsg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't treat `object` as `an array`

```
$fromName = $data->fromName;
$fromEmail = $data->fromEmail;
$msg = $data->inputMsg;
```